# Packetfence & Aruba

Tags: networking, mac-address, captive-portal, aruba

I have a fresh install of a PacketFence (PF) server.
Also, I have an Aruba networks AccessPoint (API-205), which I am using to send the users to the Captive Portal in PF.

But the captive portal returns

```
Sorry!
Your computer was not found in the PacketFence database. 
Please reboot to solve this issue.
IP address: 172.17.xx.x
MAC: 0
```

For some reason it is not getting the mac information.

packetfence.log (while trying to access the captive-portal)

```
Jan 15 17:41:46 httpd.portal(3128) INFO: [mac:[undef]] Instantiate a new iptables modification method. pf::ipset (pf::inline::get_technique)
Jan 15 17:41:46 httpd.portal(3128) WARN: [mac:[undef]] Use of uninitialized value $ip in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/local/pf/lib/pf/util.pm line 119. (pf::util::valid_ip)
Jan 15 17:41:47 httpd.portal(3130) WARN: [mac:[undef]] Unable to match MAC address to IP '172.17.xx.x' (pf::iplog::ip2mac)
```

Comment: To properly help you, lots of details should be added to your question. Anyway, I think that the right place to discuss the details of Packetfence architecture/setup is the official "user" ML (actually very activityd, and full of much-interrsting messages)

Answer (score 0):

**ip-helpers** need to be turned on in the main DHCP server. So the out-of-band PacketFence server gets the necessary DHCP information that was otherwise hidden from him in the requests.